# How many ways can we get exactly $2$ ones by rolling $6$ die ? ( Assuming order does matter )

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If the order doesn't matter then we can go this approach - Suppose we have $3$ die then there are $5$ ways to get exactly $2$ ones. Similarly for $4$ die there are $25$ ways. Going by this for $6$ die the answer is $625$ $(5^4)$. But I am unable to think what should my approach when order does matter.

Comment: Hint:  Since order matters, choose $2$ slots among the $6$ to place the $1's$ (how many ways to do that?).  Now, populate each of  the other $4$ slots with values other than $1$ (how many ways to do that?).   And finally, just multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesnt take into account the order.
You need first to calculate the amount of diffrent places the 2 dices gets the value 1
There are 15 diffrent places the 2 dices who will get the value 1
Then for each place there is 5^4=625  as you written
So in the end you got 15*625=9375 diffrent options.